# Remove Sliver Polygons with JSTS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, union, gis

Hello GIS / JavaScript folks,

I am developing a small Historical Geographic Information System project and am currently working on the geometric operations. I am developing in CoffeeScript/JavaScript and am using the JSTS library for help. While it has a great functionality, I am struggling with the documentation...

Here is the problem: I have country geometries from NaturalEarthData. I want to be able to unify neighbouring countries. Since adjacent areas are not always perfect, sometimes are these little sliver polygons between two areas on unification, which is rather ugly. I want to get rid of them, but just do not know, how.

QGIS has the great feature "Remove Sliver Polygons" which I pretty much want to have. Does anybody know how to do that in JTS / JSTS / GEOS (which I guess all originate in the same code base?)

Any help is appreciated.

[image: example: Sliver Polygons]

Answer (score 2):

After a while of thinking about it, the answer to this question is actually obvious: What you want is of course to delete these sliver polygons. They can easily identified by their size: they area incredibly small, only a fraction of the area of Vatican City, which is the smallest country in the world.

After a unification they are inner rings of a polygon and can be identified and deleted like this:

```
MIN_AREA_SIZE = 0.0000001
for innerRing, idx in polygon
   # the first is technically the outerRing, but that one usually has a larger area
   if (new jsts.geom.Polygon(innerRing).getArea() < MIN_AREA_SIZE
     polygon.slice(idx,1)  # delete inner ring from polygon
```